# Rounded Corner Menu- Current Page Item

Tags: css, menu, rounded-corners, currentitem

I'm working on a webpage that has a menu with rounded corners. I'm using a theme in WordPress and modifying it, so I'm starting with something someone else has created. I'm middle of the road when it comes to CSS and html- I can kludge things together, but it often isn't exactly elegant and advanced things are beyond me.

Anyway, my problem is this- The menu items change color when the mouse is hovered over them, and have yet a different color when the item represents the current page. The normal menu and the hover items have rounded corners, but not the current page item. This only matters for the left side of the item on the farthest left.

I did find a bit of CSS for the hover state of that item that works, which is as follows:

```
.menu > li:first-child:hover, 
.menu > li:first-child:hover a {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; }
```

However, I have no idea how to take this same principle and apply it to the current item class. This is what I tried:

```
.menu .current_page_item a > li:first-child:,
.menu  .current_menu_item a > li:first-child: {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
```

It didn't work, of course. As I say, it's really a shot in the dark.

Comment: Can you show a demo or your HTML code? [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a good way to share what's up.

Comment: Sure thing! The webpage is actually live- http://betakateenin.com/. It's the menu right there at the top. Hope that's enough. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: so you want rounded corner by default instead of hover?

Comment: `.menu li:first-child.current_page_item { .. }`

Comment: I wanted the corners to be rounded for its normal state, hover state, and when it is the current page. Abhitalks had the right of it! With one minor addition- it ended up being .menu li:first-child.current_page_item a {...}. But I wouldn't have gotten there without that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the first menu item anchor with:

```
.menu > li:first-child > a {
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
}
```

This targets:

```
the menu > the first list item inside that menu > the anchor immediately inside that list item
```

This would be safer than targeting the `.current-item` class since you're trying to target the first list item specifically to blend it with existing elements, whereas the `.current-item` class can be used on every menu item.

The problem with your original selector syntax was that this:

```
.menu .current_page_item a > li:first-child:
```

is trying to select:

```
the menu > the current list item > the anchor inside that item >
the first list item immediately inside that item
```

Most of that isn't in the page's HTML.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you!